# How to replace Datetime format to some text

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012

I have one column to display status about the machine.

Now I want if the column is null, display `END`. Else, the column should display `RUNNING`.

The column is `Datetime` format. I don't know how to replace `datetime`. I already replaced all the `null` value to `END`.

But not for `datetime` format and replace two different format in same expression.

```
=IIF(isnothing(Fields!ENDTIME.Value),"END",Fields!ENDTIME.Value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really as simple as it appears. `IIf` requires 3 parameters. The first is a boolean expression. The second is the value to be returned if the (previous) expression evaluated to `TRUE`, and the 3rd if it evaluated to `FALSE`. So replace `Fields!ENDTIME.Value` in your 3rd parameter with `"RUNNING"`:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!ENDTIME.Value),"END","RUNNING")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. i though it is so complex. because last time i was using =replace(replace())